# Proof that $ \forall x,y \in \mathbb{R} \qquad x^2+y^2+(x-1)(y-1)>0 $

Tags: real-numbers

How to proof simply that 
$$
\forall x,y \in \mathbb{R} \qquad x^2+y^2+(x-1)(y-1)>0
$$

Comment: Have you tried the problem? If you could, please show some of your own work.

Comment: Yes I can proof it by two ways (the first i use functions and the second i use a discussion about the values of x and y) but i search the most simple way.

Comment: You can use mathematical induction to support your proof.

Comment: Please take a look at Rory Daulton's solution and comment thereafter. The lower bound is $2/3$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

$$x^2+y^2+(x-1)(y-1) = x^2 + y^2 + xy - x -y+1 = \dfrac{(x+y)^2}2 + \dfrac{(x-1)^2}2 + \dfrac{(y-1)^2}2$$

Answer (score 3):

The left side of your inequality is a quadratic form with non-zero $xy$ term. Rotate the coordinates by 45 degrees and you will get an easily recognized form for an ellipse. So substitute
$$x=x'+y'$$
$$y=x'-y'$$
to get an easier form that will be easy to prove to be positive. In fact, you will get a better lower bound for your expression than zero.

Comment: Nice thought! Using your formula, I got $x^2+y^2+(x-1)(y-1)=3(u-1/3)^2+v^2+2/3$, where $x=u+v,y=u-v$.  So the lower bound is $2/3$.

Comment: @mike: Exactly!

Answer (score 1):

$x^2+y^2+(x-1)(y-1)>0\iff x^2+y^2+xy-x-y+1>0\iff2x^2+2y^2+2xy-2x-2y+2>0\iff(x-1)^2+(y-1)^2+(x+y)^2>0$ which is obviously true.

Answer (score 0):

You onle need to show that:

$$x^2+(y-1)x+y^2-y+1 > 0.$$

Try to show that  $\Delta < 0$